# Filter column with pandas to only show certain string locations

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe that has a variety of strings in it I need to filter which I am not sure how to filter.

```
    locationcode
0   T4604760374N
1   T4604760374N
2   T4604760374N
3   T4604760374N
```

I want to make only character 4 to 7 show in this column - what is the best way to do this in pandas?

I would use substring usually with SQL.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use string slicing

**Ex:**

```
s = pd.Series(['T4604760374N', 'T4604760374N', 'T4604760374N', 'T4604760374N'])
print(s.str[4:7])
```

**Output:**

```
0    476
1    476
2    476
3    476
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
df['locationcode'] = df['locationcode'].str[4:7]
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`str.slice`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.slice.html)

```
>>> s.str.slice(4,7)
0    476
1    476
2    476
3    476
```